# Parametric line intersection test

Tags: clipping

I have the following question in an exam review and I am looking for feedback about how to approach the solution. Any advice will be highly appreciated.

> "Using a parametric line intersection test, give the parameter values of the endpoints of a line from (3,3,4) to (11,8,7) clipped to the cube extending from 0 to 5 in x, y, and z"

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

The three coordinates can be handled independently.

For instance in $x$, you need to solve

$$x_0 + t (x_1-x_0) = 0$$
 and
$$x_0 + t (x_1-x_0) = x_{max}$$